# Get audio file size in MB not working - via JavaScript/ajax

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I made an HTML5 player that uses `<audio>` tags.
All the audio controllers such as `currentTime`, `duration`, `volume` work great.

However I have a problem with showing the audio size.
The audio files is located in the same server where the php script reside.

I wrote such function:

```
      $(function() {
        $.ajax('<?php echo $myfile; ?>', {
          type: 'HEAD',
          success: function(d, r, xhr) {
            myfile.innerText = "(" + xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Length') / Math.pow(1024,2) + " MB)";
          }
        });
      });
```

**Problem 1**: The filesize appears in this format `(4.98463249206543 MB)`. I tried to add also `toFixed(2)`, but it doesn't change. I want it to have it no decimal numbers, or at maximum 2 decimals.

**Problem 2**: the above size appears often. But not always, sometimes when I refresh the browser I get the size of a fragment of second and then appears `undefined`.

Is there a way I can fix those problems?
Or do it in a completely different way? PHP `filesize` doesn't seem to work. So I would stick with javascript... or maybe nodejs?

Comment: did you did `(xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Length') / Math.pow(1024,2)).toFixed()` i.e. toFixed to whole computed data

Comment: I just tried. Your solution works. Thank you. Now there is just the problem 2 left

Comment: What is your second problem i didn't understand that.

Comment: Sometimes the size shows up. (5 MB). Sometimes it shows "undefined". Random. I refresh 10 times, 6 times I get undefined and 4 I get the size.

Comment: What do you get when printing/logging just the `xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Length')` what random thing you get without dividing or any thing else?

Comment: in console I get `5226766`. In the browser `undefined`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208192/discussion-between-animesh-sahu-and-pikk).